# "define" and "endef" syntax-rules in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html#Multi_002dLine):***

> Note that lines beginning with the recipe prefix character are
>   considered part of a recipe, so any `define` or `endef` strings
>   appearing on such a line will not be considered `make` directives.

My worry is, that is ***not*** always the case.

***As evident, by the following makfile:***

```make
ifeq "x" "y"
define xxx
else
foo = 1
    endef
else
bar = 2
endif



all ::
    @echo 'foo is: "$(foo)"'
    @echo 'bar is: "$(bar)"'
```

***Running, we get:***

```console
$ make
foo is: ""
bar is: "2"
```

Going back to the makefile, it is evident that the lines ***3*** and ***4*** inside the `ifeq` directive, i.e.

```make
ifeq "x" "y"
define xxx
else
foo = 1
    endef
else
bar = 2
endif
```

are ignored by Make.

Put simply, make ignores these 2 lines, within the `define xx`

```make
else
foo = 1
```

Because they are inside a `define`, and therefore, Make does not evaluate the `else` as a *directive* (i.e. as a *else* part, for `ifeq "x" "y"`).

But, Make clearly parses that `endef` line (***5th*** line in the `ifeq` *block*), as a directive to ***end*** the *define* directive.

Hence, after ending the `define` *block* with the `endef` line, Make will parse later lines, that is:

```make
else
bar = 2
endif
```

As part of the `ifeq` block, and because the opening directive `ifeq "x" "y"` evaluated to `false`, Make will take the `else` part as a `true` statement, and assign the value `2` to the variable `bar`, and so on.

Why is all this important?

Because, clearly, Make allows here a `endef` line to be parsed as a directive, even though, it is prefixed with a `<tab>` character.

That is in clear violation of the documentation, quoted above:

> Note that lines beginning with the recipe prefix character are
>   considered part of a recipe, so any `define` or `endef` strings
>   appearing on such a line will not be considered `make` directives.

Agree?

Comment: There is no target above the endef, and therefor it can't be part of a recipe.

Comment: Try `make -f <(echo -e 'define foo\nbar=1\n\tendef\nall:;')`, and you'll get: 
`/dev/fd/63:1: *** missing 'endef', unterminated 'define'.  Stop.`. Proving, that `endef` should ***not*** (even when it is following a variable-definition-line) be parsed as a directive, when it (the `endef`) was prefixed with a <tab>.